# C# Type or namespace name could not be found in another project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

I 3 C# projects in a VS 2013 solution, one WPF project and two class libraries. Each project has its own namespace.

In the one project I have a class named MainWindowViewModel belonging to namespace ViewModels.

In the other project I have a class named BaseWindowViewModel belonging to namespace ToolBox.Base.

BaseWindowViewModel has the signature:

```
public abstract class BaseWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel, IBaseWindowViewModel
```

And the MainWindowViewModel is supposed to subclass this class, like so:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseWindowViewModel
```

I have using-references in place for the second class, and I can e.g. have MainWindowViewModel subclass any other (old) class or interface in the other project/namespace ToolBox.Base, but for some reason VS can't find BaseWindowViewModel, and neither can the compiler it uses, so I get a "The type or namespace name 'BaseWindowViewModel' could not be found (...)" error.

The funny thing is that I can't access any other NEW classes I add in the ToolBox.Base project, but I can access the old ones...

What I've tried:

- Clean and rebuild all projects / whole solution
- Copy and paste names to make sure they are correctly spelled/cased
- Created a new solution adding the same projects
- Created a new empty class to try accessing it through subclassing
- Did the above also with an entirely new class in both projects
- Checked Target Framework (.NET Framework 4.5) on all projects after something I found on here
- Double-checked project-references, even though they should be alright considering I can access the old classes in the referenced project
- Ate candy... (great for my soul, but didn't solve any problems)

Nothing worked, except:

- Copy the BaseWindowViewModel.cs file to the ViewModels project, not changing anything, not even namespace, keeping the file intact

...but that is not satisfactory for my purposes...

Any ideas? I'll be bald soon...

Comment: Did you add the necessary project references? Otherwise the usings will still give you errors.

Comment: Yes, Sebastiaan, that's in the list of of things I've checked =(... today I also tried removing that project-reference and added it again, no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that, for some reason, a new bin/Debug directory had been created and that when building the ToolBox.Base project it went into this new directory while the other project referenced the old directory!

I deleted the whole bin directory for this project and rebuilt the ToolBox.Base project, then removed and re-added the reference to that project!

Now just wondering how it came to be that the new directory was created... hmpf... anyway, problem solved! =)